# Hibernate, Order by count of subquery on ManyToMany using Predicates

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have a query written using Predicates in Hibernate and I need to add a subquery on a join table to count the number of joins and order by the number of joins where they exist in an array of ids.

The join table is a ManyToMany relation.

I am using flyway to setup the table schema, so while the join table exists in the database, a join model is not needed in Hibernate to join the 2 related models therefore no join model exists.

I don't care about retrieving these related models, I just want the number of joins so that I can order by them.

The following is PostGreSQL, which works. I need to convert the following PSQL into a Predicate based query:

```
SELECT u.*, COUNT(jui.interest_id) AS juiCount
FROM "user" u
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ui.user_id, ui.interest_id
    FROM user_interest ui
    WHERE ui.interest_id IN (?)
) AS jui ON u.id = jui.user_id
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY juiCount DESC
```

Where the ids provided for the IN condition are passed into the subquery. The above query is in PostGreSQL.

Working with what I have so far:

```
    CriteriaBuilder b = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<User> q = b.createQuery(User.class);
    Root<User> u = q.from(User.class);

    // This doesn't make sense because this is not a join table
    // Subquery<Interest> sq = q.subquery(Interest.class)
    // Root<Interest> squi = sq.from(Interest.class);
    // sq.select(squi);
    // sq.where(b.in("interest_id", new LiteralExpression<Long[]>((CriteriaBuilderImpl) b, interestIds)));

    q.orderBy(
    //    b.desc(b.tuple(u, b.count(squi))),
        b.asc(u.get(User_.id))
    );

    q.where(p);

    return em
        .createQuery(q)
        .getResultList();
```

Everything I have managed to find doesn't quite seem to fit right given that they are not using ManyToMany in the use of q.subquery() in their example.

Anyone can help fill in the blanks on this please?